# Lens function similar to `%~` but returns `Maybe`

Tags: haskell

I want a lens function that is similar to [`%~`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-37--126-), but takes a function `f` that returns a `Maybe`, and returns a `Just` with the updated value by `f` if `f` returns a `Just`, and returns a `Nothing` if `f` returns a `Nothing`.

Here's an example:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import           Control.Lens (makeLenses, (%~), (&), (.~), (^.))

newtype Foo =
  Foo
    { _bar :: Int
    }
  deriving (Show)

makeLenses ''Foo

updateFoo :: Foo -> Maybe Foo
updateFoo f = fmap (\x -> f & bar .~ x) $ doubleIfOdd $ f ^. bar

doubleIfOdd :: Int -> Maybe Int
doubleIfOdd x
  | odd x = Just $ x * 2
  | otherwise = Nothing
```

```
*Main> updateFoo (Foo 3)
Just (Foo {_bar = 6})
*Main> updateFoo (Foo 4)
Nothing
```

Is there a way to shorten `updateFoo`?

```hs
updateFoo f = f & bar <someLensFunction> doubleIfOdd
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`(%%~)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-5.1/docs/Control-Lens-Operators.html#v:-37--37--126-).

```
ghci> (1,2) & _1 %%~ \x -> if odd x then Just (x * 2) else Nothing
Just (2,2)
ghci> (2,2) & _1 %%~ \x -> if odd x then Just (x * 2) else Nothing
Nothing
```